# Помогите реализовать задачу (псевдоэлементы, jQuery, css)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, веб-программирование, frontend

Всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста, не могу сообразить, как сделать. Надо добавить для каждого  after-элемент (крестик для удаления, за границей таблицы, для удаления строки) и before-элемент для каждого выполненного элемента (по которому кликнули, который получил класс ready).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.add_task {
  background-color: #1DBB6C;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  width: 25%;
}

.add_task p {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

input,
select {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  outline: none;
}

.addButton {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #5fd298;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.addButton:hover {
  background-color: #43966c;
}


/*   TASKS    */

.tasks {
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
  padding: 60px 40px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

th,
td {
  border: 3px solid #1DBB6C;
  padding: 15px;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: rgba(29, 187, 108, 0.3);
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgba(29, 187, 108, 0.1);
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

tr.task_item:hover {
  background-color: rgba(29, 187, 108, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
}

tr:first-child {
  background-color: #fff;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.ready {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  background-color: rgba(29, 187, 108, 0.7) !important;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add_task">
  <p>Новая задача</p>
  <label for="name">Название песни:</label><br>
  <input type="text" class="myInput" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Название песни"><br>
  <label for="price">Стоимость (руб):</label><br>
  <input type="text" class="myInput" name="price" id="price" placeholder="Стоимость"><br>
  <label for="type_work">Тип работы:</label><br>
  <select name="type_work" id="type_work">
    <option value="minus">Минусовка</option>
    <option value="arrange">Аранжировка</option>
   </select><br>
  <label for="worker">Исполнитель:</label><br>
  <select name="worker" id="worker">
    <option value="yan">Ян Янов</option>
    <option value="evgen">Евгений Евгеньев</option>
    <option value="valera">Валерий Валерьев</option>
   </select><br>
  <button type="submit" class="addButton">Добавить</button>
</div>


<div class="tasks">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Название песни</th>
      <th>Стоимость работы</th>
      <th>% исполнителя</th>
      <th>Тип работы</th>
      <th>Исполнитель</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="task_item">
      <td>Numb</td>
      <td>3300</td>
      <td>1485</td>
      <td>Минусовка</td>
      <td>Ян Янов</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="task_item">
      <td>Numb</td>
      <td>3300</td>
      <td>1485</td>
      <td>Минусовка</td>
      <td>Ян Янов</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>



<script>
  $('tr.task_item').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('ready');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Добавить то можно... Но вот событие повесить уже не получится. Например, на "крестик" повесить событие удаление строчки - логично. Но, насколько я знаю, нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Дико извиняюсь за дублирование ответа с другого ресурса (но ссылки здесь не любят). Есть такой костыль:

```js
$('.popUp').click(function(){
    if (this.offsetWidth - event.offsetX < 0) {
  $('.popUp').addClass('close');
    }
});
```

```css
body,html {width:100%;height:100%;margin:0px;padding:0px;}

.popUp {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    background:#aaaaaa;
    padding:20px;
    text-align:center;
    font:50px /200px arial;
    color:#ffffff;
}
.popUp.close {
    display:none;
}
.popUp:after {
    content:'Закрыть';
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
    right:-50px;
    font:10px arial;
    color:#ff0000;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popUp">
   
    POPUP
   
</div>
```

Но это именно костыль, потому что псевдо-элементы не являются частью DOM, а значит к ним не применимы манипуляции.